# preg_match checks on variable before submit

Tags: php, if-statement, preg-match

I need to make sure some checks are made before submitting a form:

```
if ( preg_match( '/[^\d]/', $phone ) || (strlen( $phone ) < 11 ) )
```

The above statement checks that `$phone` is not less than 11 digits.

I need to make extra checks.

`$phone` must be 11 digits (no more, no less).

`$phone` must start with any of the following: `010` or `011` or `012`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this check in one regex:

```
/^01[0-2][0-9]{8}$/
```

without the need of checking length by strlen function.

Comment: so it should be if ( preg_match( '/^01[0-2][0-9]{8}$/
', $phone ) ) ???, cause like this it didn't work :D

Comment: i think it must be if not, and not if, how can i do that?

Comment: thanks it works  if ($phone =! preg_match( '/^01[0-2][0-9]{8}$/', $phone) ){

Answer (score 0):

try this regexp

> ```
>    /^(010|011|012)+\d{8}\z/
> ```

Rewrite

```
           if ( preg_match("/^(010|011|012)+\d{8}\z/",$phone))
```

> **See this regex in action**

https://eval.in/300433

Comment: i think it must be if not, and not if, how can i do that?